# SQLAlchemy ON DELETE SET NULL while using secondary table

Tags: python, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy, relationship

I encountered a basic use case - I have two tables, Nodes and Networks, and they are interconnected using third table IPAddr as a secondary association table:

```
class Node(Base, BasicValidator):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class IPAddr(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ip_addrs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    network = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('networks.id'))
    node = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))
    ip_addr = Column(String(25), nullable=False)

class Network(Base, BasicValidator):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nodes = relationship(
        "Node",
        secondary=IPAddr.__table__,
        backref="networks")
```

Now while I'm deleting Network objects from database I get the following error:

> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(9) is still referenced from table "ip_addrs". 
>   'DELETE FROM networks WHERE networks.id = %(id)s' ({'id': 6}, {'id':
>   7}, {'id': 8}, {'id': 9}, {'id': 10})

All I need to do is to *keep nodes while deleting both Network and IPAddr*.

I tried to this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#association-object but it didn't help, even with [AssociacionProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html), because this time all works but Network.nodes returns **[None]** if I do something like this and then delete nodes:

```
class Node(Base, BasicValidator):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class IPAddr(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ip_addrs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    network = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('networks.id'))
    node = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))
    nodes = relationship("Node", backref="networks_assocs")
    ip_addr = Column(String(25), nullable=False)

class Network(Base, BasicValidator):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nd = relationship("IPAddr", backref="networks")
    nodes = association_proxy('nd', 'nodes')
```

Can someone please help, what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like ON DELETE CASCADE if your database supports it.

Look here for more: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#unitofwork-cascades

Comment: I know about ON DELETE CASCADE, it doesn't work fully in this case (I'm getting an error described above). The second way seems to be more useful, but not all things are great yet.